# Axis spikes not showing up on Matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a couple of line graphs using Matplotlib and the small dashes which marks the center of the xticks are not showing up. Here is a sample plot I found online which has the marks (I circled them).

[image: Plot where marks are shown]

Now below is my code and the graph. I know it's not related to spines.

[image: My Sample Plot]

Code:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import math
sns.set()
sns.set_style("dark")
sns.set_style("white")
plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[10,5,69,38,52],label='test')
plt.xticks([1,2,3,4,5],['apple','orange','grapes','lemon','pear'],ha='right')

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=300)
```

OS: MacOX High Sierra 10.13, Python: 3.6.0 and no Virtual Environments

Comment: What you show is not the complete code or you run this code in some environment where additional settings have been made, which are not part of the question. Question which do not show a complete reproducible example are useless. See [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the posts with full code, OS and python version details.

Comment: You are using seaborn styles which set the ticks invisible. Remove all lines which start with `sns` from the code and you will see the ticks.

Comment: It worked when I removed my Seaborn styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customise the seaborn styles to add back ticks (there is also a style for ticks). See [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html) for the full details.

Just change your `set_style` line to have a second parameter which is a dictionary of overrides. In this case it is setting the size of the xticks. That link gives the full details of built-in styles and all the options for overriding.

`sns.set_style("white", {"xtick.major.size": 5})`

Comment: Yes, this works. I could now have the Seaborne styles and the marks.